# Why is the deployment zone is greyed out in AWS api gateway deployment?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I would like to know why the deplyment zone is still grey i've tried a lot of things but it's still grey ....

I'am trying to make an api from a lambda

[image: I'am da grey]

thanks and regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to deploy the API first which will create the deployment and ask you to create a stage. This step is not totally clear in my opinion.

[image]